# iPhone SDK: NSMutableArray unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray which gets objects added to it from an NSDictionary.
These objects are values of either 1 or 0.
I am trying to loop through this NSMutableArray, to check each value. If it is 1, I set add a green tick image to an array, if it is zero, I add a red cross image to an array.

However I am getting the following error on checking the values of the NSMutableArray:

```
[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Here is my code:

```
     facilitiesAvailable = [NSMutableArray new];

     [facilitiesAvailable addObject:[[InfoDictionary valueForKey:@"wc-avail"]copy]];
     [facilitiesAvailable addObject:[[InfoDictionary valueForKey:@"wifi_avail"]copy]];

    tixArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for(NSString *avail in facilitiesAvailable) {

        if([avail isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

            [tixArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenTick.png"]];
        } else {

            [tixArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redCross.png"]];
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing what is in your InfoDictionary, a good answer will most likely not appear.  Are they truly values or NSStrings that hole character 1 or 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message:

```
 [__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

means that `avail` is an NSArray object and not an NSString as you expected, hence the error. You should check how you populate your `InfoDictionary` dictionary, since it  comes from there.

Comment: @sergio - Thats essentially what I put in my comment above, and yours should be a comment, not an answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, what happens if you replace your code with this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [facilitiesAvailable count]; i++) {
    NSString * avail = (NSString *)[facilitiesAvailable objectAtIndex:i];

    if([avail isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [tixArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenTick.png"]];
    } else {              
        [tixArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redCross.png"]];         
    }
}
```

This also ASSUMES that the objects being added to facilitiesAvailable are based on the objects in your InfoDictionary truly being NSString objects.  This CASTS them to NSString objects, but you will get odd behavior if they arent truly that from the InfoDictionary.

Comment: It most likely crashes for the reason that the object coming from your NSDictionary that you are putting into your NSMutableArray are not strings.