# how to display json response in each row in uitableview

Tags: objective-c

After parsing am storing response in an array.From that array am picking key value pair using valueForKey and storing in another array.
how to display json response in each row in uitableview .Am getting whole response in one row

```
arrTotalRequests=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

str= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"user_id"];

NSString *strJson=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userId=%@",str];
NSString *strlength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[strJson length]];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:strlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
NSData *requestData=[strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&err];

NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSLog(@"response is %@",strResponse);
//        [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
arr1=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
arr2=[arr1 valueForKey:@"result"];
arrTotalRequests = [arr2 valueForKey:@"description"];
   }
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [arrTotalRequests count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier=@"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
}
NSString *str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  [arrTotalRequests valueForKey:@"description"]];
NSLog(@"new desc is %@",str2);
cell.textLabel.text=str2;
}
```

Comment: As above - we need to see what you have done so far and what you're trying to do. Show us the code, please.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You've got an array of values, you've got a table view, you've got cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Index into your array, fetch the data, and place it into the cell.

Comment: One problem you've got is mismatched `{}` chars.  There's a `{` after `if (cell == nil)`, but it appears to have no mate.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `[arrTotalRequests valueForKey:@"description"]`?

Comment: this is json response[{"result":[{"request_id":1,"ticket_number":"P_101","email":"xx","user_id":4,"description":"fjdyhsrwgk","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":2,"ticket_number":"P_102","email":"yyy","user_id":4,"description":"hi","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":3,"ticket_number":"P_103","email":"aaa","user_id":4,"description":"hii","status":"initiated"},{"request_id":4,"ticket_number":"P_104","email":"bbb","user_id":4,"description":"aa..","status":"initiated"}]}]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this..

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return [arrTotalRequests count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *identifier=@"cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    cell.textLabel.text=[[arrTotalRequests valueForKey:@"description"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. i am getting error

Comment: see this link for this error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020544/iphone-sdk-nsmutablearray-unrecognized-selector

Comment: I mean arrTotalRequests this is immutable array. So make it mutable array.

Comment: same as before am getting whole response in first row instead of getting one by one in each row